# How to use flash() with session in cakephp 3.3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm beginner in programming, i use cakephp 3.3 version and i want to understand how to activate session and use  in controller and how to send flash message like this:$this->session->flash('items was updated'). What line have to add to activate session and where, how to use correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.co.nz/url?q=http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj8soeQ6N7QAhWGzbwKHTXsCuQQFggLMAA&sig2=Yi_7YH9XKwQ3sZvzd0kpeA&usg=AFQjCNGz10_vrov2Lw7bCkB5sgc2b8asOA

have a look on here

have you used setFlash in the controller and are you using the default layout??

have you also followed the blog tutorial i think that went over using flash messages ands its a great tutorial

Comment: Man SessionComponent::setFlash() is deprecated. You should use Flash instead in version 3.3. You could help with a concrete example. I'm using flash without session to send message and is working..but with session not working.

Comment: I'm waiting for other opinions !